# Adicionar login no projeto android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Pessoal desculpa se isso for muito trivial, mas estou começando a estudar android, eu tenho um projeto exemplo que você adiciona nota e edita elas, esse projeto ja esta funcionando com essa mainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private NotesAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<Note> notesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private TextView noNotesView;

    private DatabaseHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        noNotesView = findViewById(R.id.empty_notes_view);

        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        notesList.addAll(db.getAllNotes());

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showNoteDialog(false, null, -1);
            }
        });

        mAdapter = new NotesAdapter(this, notesList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new MyDividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, 16));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        toggleEmptyNotes();

        /**
         * On long press on RecyclerView item, open alert dialog
         * with options to choose
         * Edit and Delete
         * */
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this,
                recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, final int position) {
                showActionsDialog(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                showActionsDialog(position);
            }
        }));
    }

    /**
     * Inserting new note in db
     * and refreshing the list
     */
    private void createNote(String note) {
        // inserting note in db and getting
        // newly inserted note id
        long id = db.insertNote(note);

        // get the newly inserted note from db
        Note n = db.getNote(id);

        if (n != null) {
            // adding new note to array list at 0 position
            notesList.add(0, n);

            // refreshing the list
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            toggleEmptyNotes();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updating note in db and updating
     * item in the list by its position
     */
    private void updateNote(String note, int position) {
        Note n = notesList.get(position);
        // updating note text
        n.setNote(note);

        // updating note in db
        db.updateNote(n);

        // refreshing the list
        notesList.set(position, n);
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);

        toggleEmptyNotes();
    }

    /**
     * Deleting note from SQLite and removing the
     * item from the list by its position
     */
    private void deleteNote(int position) {
        // deleting the note from db
        db.deleteNote(notesList.get(position));

        // removing the note from the list
        notesList.remove(position);
        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

        toggleEmptyNotes();
    }

    /**
     * Opens dialog with Edit - Delete options
     * Edit - 0
     * Delete - 0
     */
    private void showActionsDialog(final int position) {
        CharSequence colors[] = new CharSequence[]{"Edit", "Delete"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Choose option");
        builder.setItems(colors, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (which == 0) {
                    showNoteDialog(true, notesList.get(position), position);
                } else {
                    deleteNote(position);
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }


    /**
     * Shows alert dialog with EditText options to enter / edit
     * a note.
     * when shouldUpdate=true, it automatically displays old note and changes the
     * button text to UPDATE
     */
    private void showNoteDialog(final boolean shouldUpdate, final Note note, final int position) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflaterAndroid = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
        View view = layoutInflaterAndroid.inflate(R.layout.note_dialog, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilderUserInput = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertDialogBuilderUserInput.setView(view);

        final EditText inputNote = view.findViewById(R.id.note);
        TextView dialogTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title);
        dialogTitle.setText(!shouldUpdate ? getString(R.string.lbl_new_note_title) : getString(R.string.lbl_edit_note_title));

        if (shouldUpdate && note != null) {
            inputNote.setText(note.getNote());
        }
        alertDialogBuilderUserInput
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(shouldUpdate ? "update" : "save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogBox, int id) {

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogBox, int id) {
                                dialogBox.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilderUserInput.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Show toast message when no text is entered
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(inputNote.getText().toString())) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter note!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                } else {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }

                // check if user updating note
                if (shouldUpdate && note != null) {
                    // update note by it's id
                    updateNote(inputNote.getText().toString(), position);
                } else {
                    // create new note
                    createNote(inputNote.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Toggling list and empty notes view
     */
    private void toggleEmptyNotes() {
        // you can check notesList.size() > 0

        if (db.getNotesCount() > 0) {
            noNotesView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            noNotesView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Então la na pastinha do view, eu fui com o botão direito e adiocenei uma nova LoginActivity, o android criou uma classe java e um xml, com os padrões dele.

O que eu queria, que na primeira vez que eu iniciasse meu projeto, ele pedisse as informações na tela de login, (por enquanto ta com password e login, depois quero pedir o nome e uma imagem), e quando a pessoa clicasse no botão fosse para a tela de inserir as notas, depois da primeira vez que a pessoa inseriu as informações de login, ela não fosse mais solicitada, mas houvesse a opção de editar.

Atualmente a minha xml da main esta assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="info.androidhive.sqlite.view.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar ou apontar que alterações eu deveria fazer?

Estou com duvida principalmente, porque para inserir a notas eu tive de criar uma classe para sqlite, tanto para fazer a criação da base, como uma para o modelo das notas, no caso da login eu terei que fazer também? Ou já existe uma trativa disso no android padrão?

Imagino que o teste de já existir o login fazer feito no onCreate da main, mas não faço ideia de como fazer uma condicional para aparecer tela de login, ou a tela das notas. E nem como na activity padrão de login, como faço para assim que inserir as informações ir para a outra tela.

Comment: Como disse ai no final, eu faço exatamente isso verifico na main se já foi logado a primeira vez. Caso não startActivity(new Intent(Main.this,Login.class)). Mas da uma olhada nesse tutorial pode te ajudar https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_login_screen.htm

Comment: Eu tinha visto esse tutorial, mas as classes deles são bem direferentes das geradas pelo android studio 3.0 . E onde entraria essa linha que vc me disse? Esse Login.class é a LoginActivity.java ?

Comment: Você já possui um tela de login ? Esse login será salvo de que forma ? Online ou Offline? usará o firebase ? se Sim, o mesmo possui recursos para validação se o usuário está conectado, a lógica seria vc criar um metodo na activity main, no oncreate, que valida se o usuário é igual a null, se sim, então chama a activity ou fragment de login

Comment: Ja possuo uma tela de login, ele sera salvo offline, no caso acredito com SQLite imagino que assim como fiz para o note, tenho que fazer um modelo para persistir ele na base?